# How do I auto indent a long method after typing in the finish semicolon in XCode5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a long method, after I type it in, it looks like this:

```
[someObj action1:param1 action2:param2 action3:param3 action4:param4];
```

But I want it to become like this... :

```
[someObj action1:param1
         action2:param2
         action3:param3
         action4:param4];
```

...automatically after I type in the last semicolon.

I just saw a video that did this, so how do I do that?
(It is a paid video so can't give link here)

Comment: ask the creator of the video?

Comment: wasnt he pressing enter after adding each param? like, param enter tab param enter tab etc... when u write the semicolon it automatically indents it.

Comment: I set the preference that makes <tab> always indent, then I can select-all and hit tab to re-indent the entire source file.

Comment: @Chiquis He wasn't, all the code was in one line, then after he pressed the last semicolon, the code became nicely indented.

Comment: @bbum That's a good trick, but in my description, if I don't insert "ENTER" before actions in a method, it is still in one line after doing an re-indenting to it. And I want to save the time to press "ENTER" to every action in a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/travisjeffery/ClangFormat-Xcode.

It will reformat your code to adhere to style rules, like Chromium's for example, where the line length is 80 chars max.
In this case, the method will be wrapped as you mentioned if it's more than 80 chars.

You can either reformat on a particular key combination, or on each save.

Answer (score 3):

For the question text:

```
[someObj action1:param1 action2:param2 action3:param3 action4:param4];
```

if you have already entered that on one line just select the space between parameters and <kbd>return</kbd>
That will tend to alligh the colon ":" characters on multiple lines.

To auto-indent already entered code select the text that you would like auto-indented and then <kbd>control</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> and that selection will be indented to Xcode rules.

I use that all the time.

If you just want to move a selected block of code to the left <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>[</kbd>, to the right <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: And if you're about to type it, just hit return after each segment.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I still need to press Enter between actions when I input.